# Access custom view's user-defined runtime attributes from initWithCoder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, initwithcoder

I have instances of a custom view class in a XIB that I need to initialize by calling a custom initializer that takes certain parameters. In order to configure these in interface builder I need to pass those parameters somehow to the initializer, i.e. `initWithCoder` so I can redirect that to the correct initializer.

So I'm thinking the user-defined runtime attributes would be perfect for this, but can't find any info on how to access these from the coder object passed to `initWithCoder`.

Does anyone know how to do this, or alternatively have another way that I can initialize a custom (third-party) view class that has its own custom initializer method from a XIB? I can tweak the class a bit but I don't want to rewrite it.

**Update:** I ended up just modifying the class to have a separate `setup` method instead of doing all the setup in the initializer, which makes things a lot easier. However I'm still curious if this is even possible the other way.